# Replacement for System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry for .net 4.8

Tags: .net, dll

recently I have to migrate my project from .net framework 4.5 to .net 4.8
There is issue for System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ValidatingIssuerNameRegistry as it is support until ver 4.5 only.

Is there any suggestion for replacement any dll that works the same as this one, but compatible for .net 4.8 ? Thank you

Try see Microsoft.IdentityModel.Validators but unsure on the function.